# How can I remap the windows key functions?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

On Windows 7, you can use the "Windows" key in combination with the arrow keys to move windows around on the screen. I'd like to change this behavior (or expand it) so that I can use the "Windows" key in combination with hjkl to achieve the exact same behavior as the arrow keys (but with easier vim-like access).

Has anyone had any success doing something like this?

Comment: Have you tried [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the tip from @[Darth Android](https://superuser.com/questions/621405/how-can-i-remap-the-windows-key-functions#comment772386_621405) or use a program that does this, for example the tool [KeyTweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/) that remap, enable/disable keys.